# How to find a condition for direction of motion in a system with hanging pulley?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following system once it is released from rest.

[image]

We assume that:

- the masses of the two fixed pulleys attached to the ceiling are negligible
- the mass of the rope is negligible
- the friction between the rope and the pulleys is negligible

I understand that the moveable pulley of mass $m_3$ will accelerate downwards if $m_3> m_1+m_2$, upwards if $m_3< m_1+m_2$ and and that the system will remain in equilibrium if $m_3= m_1+m_2$.

However, I can't quite figure out similar conditions that determine the direction of motion of each of the two blocks.

I think that the lighter of the two blocks will always accelerate in the direction opposite to the direction of motion of the moveable pulley, is that right?

However, for the remaining heavier block, I'm getting a bit lost!

For example, if $m_3>m_1+m_2$ and $m_1>m_2$, I feel like $m_1$ can still accelerate in either direction, and that there is some third inequality relating the three masses that determines that direction which I can't quite figure out.

I've tried drawing free body diagrams for each object but it doesn't seem to help.

Any help is therefore greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit: Further clarification.**

I would like to know in what direction each of these acceleration vectors should be pointing depending on what the size of the masses are. For example, if we are given that $m_2=5$ kg and $m_3=10$ kg, I would like to know for what values of $m_1$ will $m_1$ accelerate upwards and for what values will it accelerate downwards.

For example, to find the magnitudes of the tension and acceleration vectors, we will eventually need to apply Newton's second law to mass $m_1$. The correct equation to use is either $T-m_1g = m_1a_1$ or it's $T-m_1g = m_1(-a_1)$ (as the equation depends on the relative directions of the tension, weight and acceleration vectors.). How do we determine which of these two equations sis the onw we should use?

(Also, note that rotational motion is being ignored.)

**Edit: More clarification.**

Let's assume that I choose the same coordinate system for all three objects with the positive direction being downwards.

Let's assume that the mass of the moveable pulley is greater than the sum of the masses of the blocks and it will therefore accelerate downwards. Its equations is then $m_3g-2T=m_3a_3$.

The lighter of the two blocks (I believe) will definitely accelerate in the opposite direction. If the lighter block is $m_2$ then, $m_2g-T=-m_2a_2$.

The heavier of the two blocks (I believe) could move in either direction. Therefore, the equation could be either $m_1g-T=m_1a_2$ or $m_1gT=-m_1a_2$.

Depending on the choice, I will then obtain either $2a_3 = -a_1 - a_2$ or $2a_3 = -a_1 + a_2$. However, that is not an issue - both equations are equally correct as the wrong sign would have been assigned to $a_1$ in one of these cases.

My question, however, is that I want my students to draw their free body diagrams correctly before they start applying Newton's second law to the situation above. For example, if $m_1=4$ kg, $m_2=2$ kg and $m_3=10$ kg, I want to students to say:

"Well, $m_3$ definitely accelerates downwards as its heavier than the sum of the other two objects. $m_2$ definitely accelerates upwards as its the lighter of the two blocks and therefore accelerates in the opposite direction to $m_3$. $m_1$ definitely accelerates..."

How do they finish that sentence?

More generally, let's assume that $m_3>m_1+m_2$ and $m_1>m_2$. The question I am asking is the following:

"For what values of $m_1$ will the object of mass $m_1$ accelerate upwards, and for what values will it accelerate downwards?"

How do I answer that question?

There must be some additional inequality relating the three masses that answers that question. What is that inequality?

**Edit: More clarification.**

The effects of rotation must be ignored. Rotational motion is not on the syllabus.

The question I am asking is based on the high school syllabus that has been in place in my country for the past 30 years and questions like my scenario are are asked almost every year in my country's end of school exams.

For example, here is a question on the syllabus relating to this diagram from the school book that almost every school in my country uses.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG2hH.jpg

and question 4 (b) in the below paper is an example of such a question from an official end of school examination.

https://www.examinations.ie/archive/markingschemes/2016/LC020ALP000EV.pdf

Based on the assumptions made in those questions, what is the answer to my more general question?

"Assume that $m_3>m_1+m_2$ and $m_1>m_2$. For what values of $m_1$ will the object of mass $m_1$ accelerate upwards, and for what values will it accelerate downwards?"

For example, in the question from the schoolbook I linked to, how did they know that the acceleration vector for the 2 kg object should have been drawn upwards rather than downwards?

Comment: You wrongly assume the tension from both sides of hanging pulley is the same. It is not - since pulley rotates you have to write equation of rotational motion for the hanging pulley.

Comment: Hi Marko, 

I've just added more clarification to my question. Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: If it is too complicated to immediately know the direction then you don’t waste time trying to guess right. You just make any assumption and solve. If your assumption was wrong you simply get a negative number. You should not be trying to teach students some complicated rule here. Just teach them to solve the system

Comment: Hi Dale, 

That is what I've been doing thus far in my teaching career. However, for many reasons related to the syllabus that I won't go in to, I would prefer if the students whatever this relation is.

Not only that, but it is entirely possible that students may be asked the question the question that I have presented. 

"For the diagram above, Assume that m_3>m_1+m_2 and m_1>m_2. For what values of m_1 will the object of mass m_1 accelerate upwards, and for what values will it accelerate downwards?"

Even ignoring the fact that I'm a teacher, what is the approach to answering it? :)

Comment: You should fix your syllabus then. Any syllabus that leads to this being an important question is a bad syllabus. I honestly can’t even imagine what kind of a syllabus could reasonably lead to this. The approach to answer it is obvious: guess, solve, and see if your guess leads to negative numbers

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have that power, it is decided by the Department of Education. :)

Do you know how to to approach the question in quotation marks in my last comment? Thanks!

Comment: Ignore that I am teacher and let's try to answer the question for curiosity.

"For the diagram above, assume that $m_3>m_1+m_2$ and $m_1>m_2$. For what values of $m_1$ will the object of mass $m_1$ accelerate upwards, and for what values will it accelerate downwards?"

The question I am asking should have a simple answer, I believe something of the form $m_1>am_2+bm_3$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I just cannot figure out how to approach finding those constants.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I understand that the moveable pulley of mass m3 will accelerate ... upwards if m3<m1+m2" consider m1=1, m2=5, and m3=4 and then consider m1=2, m2=5, and m3=4. According to your rule m3 should go up in both cases, but it doesn't. This whole approach is a bad idea.

Comment: I have two rules, not one, both which have to be true. The first rule is $m_3 > m_2+m_1$, which is not true in either of your examples. I think you might have to reread what my question was.

Anyway, I have figured out the answer regardless, thanks to Marko's tip. The heavier of the two blocks of mass $m_1$ will accelerate up only when $m_1 > \frac{m_2m_3}{4m_2-m_3}$.

Comment: Only that first rule is true. The second rule is not. Plug in the numbers, actually work it out. It shows the folly of this approach

Comment: @James You might want to double check your condition for $m_1$. For mass $m_1$ to accelerate upward I get condition $m_1 < \frac{3 m_2 m_3}{4 m_2 + m_3}$; similarly, the condition to accelerate downward is $m_1 > \frac{3 m_2 m_3}{4 m_2 + m_3}$.

Comment: “the system will remain in equilibrium if 3=1+2” This is also not correct. The system will not be in equilibrium unless 1=2
in addition to your stated condition. With the assumptions of m3>m1 + m2 and m1>m2 I get Marlo’s formula. But of course, that is not generally true, and if you remove the assumptions the formula is more complicated, including for m3. There is no simple general rule to be taught here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find conditions for the masses such that certain acceleration is positive or negative. The best way to do that is to express all accelerations as a function of masses

$$a_i = f_i (m_1, m_2, m_3, g)$$

You have to set *equations of linear motion* for the three masses, and *equation of rotational motion* for the hanging pulley. It seems to me that you are confused by "guessing the right acceleration direction". You do not have to guess anything, just setup a coordinate system with positive direction and then write equations of motion with respect to this coordinate system.

Let $x = 0$ be the position of fixed pulleys, with positive direction pointing downwards. Then

$$x_1 + x_2 + 2 x_3 = L$$

where $L$ is the total length of the stiff massless string which is constant. If you take second (time) derivative of the above equation you get

$$a_1 + a_2 + 2 a_3 = 0 \tag 1$$

The fixed pulleys are considered massless, which means tensions from the both sides have equal magnitude. Using this fact we can now write equations of motion for the three masses

$$
\begin{aligned}
m_1 a_1 &= m_1 g - T_1 \\
m_2 a_2 &= m_2 g - T_2 \\
m_3 a_3 &= m_3 g - T_1 - T_2
\end{aligned} \tag 2
$$

Equations (1) and (2) give 4 equations with 5 unknowns. The last missing equation is equation of rotational motion for the hanging pulley. If we take counterclockwise direction to be positive, the equation of rotational motion is

$$T_2 r_3 - T_1 r_3 = I_3 \alpha_3$$

where $I_3$ is moment of inertia, $\alpha_3$ is angular acceleration and $r_3$ is radius of the hanging pulley. Since pulley can be modelled as a cylinder with $I = \frac{1}{2} M R^2$, the above equation becomes

$$T_2 - T_1 = \frac{1}{2} m_3 (\alpha_3 r_3) \tag 3$$

Now you need to relate angular acceleration $\alpha$ to linear acceleration $a$, which is straightforward for rolling without slipping. In your example there are two possible cases, because linear acceleration of the hanging pulley can be both positive and negative for positive angular acceleration:

$$\alpha_3 r_3 = +a_3 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \alpha_3 r_3 = -a_3$$

You also mention in your question that the rotational motion of the hanging pulley can be neglected. Since the hanging pulley has non-negligible mass, the rotational motion of the pulley can be neglected only if its radius is small enough such that $I_3 \approx 0$. In that case the Eq. (3) becomes

$$T_2 - T_1 = 0 \tag 4$$

Now it is possible to find unique solution from Eqs. (1), (2), and (4)

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_1 &= \bigl(1 - 4 m_2 m_3 / (4 m_1 m_2 + m_2 m_3 + m_1 m_3) \bigr) g \\
a_2 &= \bigl(1 - 4 m_1 m_3 / (4 m_1 m_2 + m_2 m_3 + m_1 m_3) \bigr) g \\
a_3 &= \bigl(1 - 8 m_1 m_2 / (4 m_1 m_2 + m_2 m_3 + m_1 m_3) \bigr) g
\end{aligned}
$$

The system is in equilibrium when all three accelerations are zero which is true when

$$m_1 = m_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad m_3 = m_1 + m_2 \qquad \text{(Equilibrum)}$$

From the expressions for acceleration you can find conditions such that $a_1$ is always positive or negative etc. The bottom line is that you should not try to analyze problems on an intuitive level, but rather write down equations. When you purely rely on intuition, it often happens that you overlook something important.

Comment: Hi Marko, I replied to this comment below.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi Marko, I've just edited my post. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your new response. I'll add some more to my question shortly as I don't  think it answered my question unfortunately. I'll add another comment once I've completed the edit. :)

Comment: Just updated my question, thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi Marko, 

I've added more clarification to my question. Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: Hi Marko, solving those four equations will give you the value of $T$, $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$. However, I am instead looking for an equation (more specifically, an inequality) that relates the three masses.

Comment: @James I edited my answer to further clarify few points. See if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have figured it out. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @James I am glad it helped. If you feel my post answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Done, thanks again! :)