# What is the constraint acceleration equation of the system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string, constrained-dynamics

[image: Problem 57]

In the question there is a hint given, $y_A$ is not constant. From this hint I began to look at the pulley that holds $m_1$ and $m_2$, and can see that it has the same tension as $m_3$. From this observation, I (think I) have a means to involve all the masses within a given equation.

My force equation for pulley A is $$T_B - (m_1 + m_2)g = (m_1 + m_2)a$$

and for $m_3$
$$T_B-m_3 g= m_3 a$$

Solving both equations for $T_B$ and setting equal to each other I get
$$m_1 a + m_2 a + (m_1 + m_2)g = m_3 g + m_3 a$$

and then solving for a I get
$$a= \frac{m_3 g - (m_1 + m_2)g}{m_1 + m_2 - m_3}$$

What I would like to know is if my assumption about pulley 2 is correct and my subsequent work.

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure is not correct. This looks like a homework problem, so I just give few hints:

- write equations with respect to some inertial reference frame, such as ground
- each mass has its own acceleration - this is very important!
- since pulley is considered massless, tension in the cable from both sides has equal magnitude
- write equations of motion for the three masses separately; this will give you 3 equations with 5 unknowns ($a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $T_A$, and $T_B$)
- to find unique solution you need 2 more equations: (i) equation of motion for the pulley A will give relationship between tensions $T_A$ and $T_B$, and (ii) displacements for the three masses will give relationship between accelerations $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$.

Here are links to my answers to similar problems that can help you with setting up the equations:

[What is positive rotation direction of a pulley in the Atwood machine?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/697317/149541)

[How to find a condition for direction of motion in a system with hanging pulley?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696685/149541)

Comment: This procedure is the only sane way that I know of to approach problems like this.