# How to find accelerations/tensions here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

$m_{2} = 6 m$, $m_{1} = m$, $m_{3} = 3 m$

I used conservation of string length and got $a_{3} + a_{pulley} + a_{1} = a_{2}$ and $T_{1} = 2 T_{2}$, but I have a feeling it's wrong because if the pulley doesn't have a mass, then will its acceleration be infinite? $T_{1} = m_{3} a_{3}$. $T_{2} - m_{1} g = m_{1}  a_{1}$. $m_{2} g - T_{2} = m_{2} a_{2}$. But I don't know what to do with the pulley. Could you help?

Comment: There are number of problems similar to this one already discussed here. Check here one the most recent questions and links therein for some guidelines: [What is the constraint acceleration equation of the system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/701331/what-is-the-constraint-acceleration-equation-of-the-system)

Comment: Yes, thank you!